How to calculate pressure necessary to push air bubble out of capillary
An air bubble is kept by surface tension at the bottom of a capillary. The capillary is sealed at the bottom, where the air bubble sits.
How to calculate the pressure necessary to push the air bubble out of the capillary?

A diagram would be helpful; where is the pressure applied that you're referring to, if the capillary is sealed? Why would increasing the overall pressure dislodge the bubble? What are you ultimately trying to do: obtain a physics model of the energies involved, or develop an engineering approach to remove the bubble? (Or both?)
